# concatenation using '+' symbol gives me error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'current quarter' to data type int."

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i'm trying to concat few strings using  + symbol... when i use concat function it is working fine but when i use '+' symbol to concat the strings it throws an error.

Anyone know why this issue happening ?
below is the code using concat which works fine

```
    Begin
    DECLARE @VAR1 AS VARCHAR(60)
    SET @VAR1 = concat ((SELECT MIN(TimeDimension_Year) FROM TimeDimension_LU WHERE TimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = 15), '-','current quarter')
    SELECT @VAR1
    end
```

below is the same code using  '+' symbol but gets failed

```
    Begin
    DECLARE @VAR1 AS VARCHAR(60)
    SET @VAR1 = (SELECT MIN(TimeDimension_Year) FROM TimeDimension_LU WHERE TimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = 15)+ '-'+'current quarter'
    SELECT @VAR1
    end
```

Comment: `concat` performs an implicit cast to string, and `+` doesn't. `CAST(SELECT ......... AS VARCHAR(10)) + ....`

Comment: thanks got worked....

Comment: Apparently, there's no need for me to post an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously something is not a string.  That would be the `TimeDimension_Year` column.  So:

```
SET @VAR1 = (SELECT CAST(MIN(TimeDimension_Year) as varchar(255))
             FROM TimeDimension_LU
             WHERE TimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = 15
            ) + '-' + 'current quarter';
```

This is a bit verbose for my tastes.  I would just go with:

```
SELECT @VAR1 = CAST(MIN(TimeDimension_Year) as varchar(255)) + '-' + 'current quarter'
FROM TimeDimension_LU
WHERE TimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = 15;
```